# prisma query change add custom column in select and update field

Tags: mysql, orm, prisma

Below is the snippet with comments that, we are planning to achieve with Prisma [orm](https://www.prisma.io/docs) query, which is quite possible in raw SQL.

```
class User {
  id: number;
  type: 'custom' | 'default' | 'legacy';
  name: string;
  email: string;
  dep?: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date

}

prisma.users.findMany({
        where: {
          type: {in : ['custom', 'legacy']},
        },
        select:{
          type: // constant as 'custom'
          dep: true // want to alert it to department
        }
        // add new property, not part of schema
        createdBy: 'System' 
      })
```

Not able to find anything in the doc related to requirements here.

1. set a constant value for a field here e.g. type to custom
2. change filed/column name e.g. dep -> department
3. add new filed/column which is not part of table schema

Comment: For your point 2 - It looks like you need to use @map: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#map
For Point 3 - Do you mean something like a computed column which is dependent on existing columns?